# How can I deploy multiple Project Templates in Visual Studio 2012 with a single VSIX file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix

I have created several project templates for my developers to use, but cannot find a way to deploy them all within a single VSIX file.  Currently, I have 2 multi-project templates that have 4 projects within each.

I have tried to add both ZIP files to a single VSIX package but the package name shows up in the project item list.  That's not what I want.  Example..

MyVSIXPackage
    Project1.zip
    Project2.zip

In the project list, I see "MyVSIXPackage" in the list instead of "Project1" and "Project2".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

VSIX Assets section allow adding multiple project templates;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="HelloWorld..gs30ad3a-2cfc-4931-8d0c-557ed21497d3" Version="1.0.0.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Your name" />
    <DisplayName>Hello world templates</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Visual Studio templates for creating hello world project in different technologies.</Description>
    <MoreInfo>http://www.google.com</MoreInfo>
    <License>License.txt</License>
    <GettingStartedGuide>GettingStarted.txt</GettingStartedGuide>
    <ReleaseNotes>ReleaseNotes.txt</ReleaseNotes>
    <Icon>HelloWorld_icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>HelloWorld_preview.png</PreviewImage>
    <Tags>wpf windows</Tags>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0,]" />   
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5.1,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>   
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="File" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:TargetPath="ProjectTemplates\Windows\HelloWorld.zip" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="File" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:TargetPath="ProjectTemplates\WPF\HelloWorldWPF.zip" />    
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

export template for each project , extract them, add one root.vstemplate like below.

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
<TemplateData>
    <Name>imagesample</Name>
    <TemplateGroupID>WinRT-Managed</TemplateGroupID>
    <Description>An example of an image template</Description>
    <Icon>Aha-Soft-Standard-Portfolio-Ico-design.ico</Icon>
       <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<TargetPlatformName>Windows</TargetPlatformName>
    <RequiredPlatformVersion>8</RequiredPlatformVersion>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>           
    <SolutionFolder Name="WindowsPhone8">
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="PhoneApp1">
              PhoneApp1\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="PhoneApp2">
               PhoneApp2\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </SolutionFolder>
        </ProjectCollection>
</TemplateContent>
```

Now you have three files project1, project2 and one text file, zip all three together. Add this zip file to your vsix project->manifest file->assets.